# Image zoom for Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools, zooming

I whant to include image zoomer like that http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/ in my page, but I don't found any similar library for mootools. Here its my page image look like:

[image: cetered width and height]

I tried this:

http://mootools.net/forge/p/zoomer

But it zooms inner image (not near it) and break all my images design (images is cetered by width and height)

```
here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/94PLv/
```

Comment: can you make a fiddle with one demo image?

Comment: here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/94PLv/

Comment: Was that what you were looking for?

Comment: your code looks good, but for me need some method or library, witch do that: when I moseover on image and I drag mauose aroud it, near the image displays other layer with bigger visual.

Comment: Was this what you looked for jsfiddle.net/Tpccv/2  ?

Answer (score 1):

- **OPTION 1:**
- Zooming inside the image div

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/TLvr2/2/)

You need something like:

```
document.getElements('.inner a').addEvent('click', function (e) {
    e.stop();
    dragit = this.getElement('img').makeDraggable();
    this.getElement('img').removeClass('max_limit');
});
```

I fixed your fiddle a bit, is this what you were looking for? I removed some of your inline CSS and added Mootools More so you can have drag instead of scrollbars.

Added also

```
document.getElements('.fotoDiv .inner img').addClass('max_limit');
document.getElements('.fotoDiv .inner img').setProperty('style','');
```

to "put things back" on the next thumb click.

- **OPTION 2:**
- using [**Louper**](http://mootools.net/forge/p/louper) plugin

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Tpccv/2/)**

Code added:

```
//NEW ADDED
document.getElements('.inner a').addEvent('click', function(event) {
    event.stop();
});
var loupe = {
    src: 'http://img.artlebedev.ru/studio/us/2009/loup.png',
    x: 101,
    y: 102,
    radius: 85
};
document.getElements('a.click').addEvent('click', function(event) {
    var id = this.getProperty('rel');
    var target_el = document.id('im_' + id).getElement('img');
    new Louper(target_el, {
        big: target_el.src,
        radius: 80,
        loupe: loupe,
        onReady: function() {
            this.loupeWrapper.setStyles({
                left: this.smallSize.width - this.loupeSize.width + 60,
                top: this.smallSize.height - this.loupeSize.height + 120
            });
        }
    });
});
```